# How to open Settings of Android Phone on a button click in our Android App

Tags: android

I have a problem that I want to open Phone's Setting Screen on a Alert Dialog Ok button click. Means In my App I have a Dialog in which there are two buttons Ok and Cancel, I want to open Phone's Setting Screen on Ok Button Click, I don't know how to do that? please suggest me the right result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Further details: http://weimenglee.blogspot.com.es/2013/06/android-tip-programmatically-displaying.html

Answer (score 59, accepted):

this should do it

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
```

starts settings activity for result

Comment: can i just use startActivity?

Comment: You  should only use startActivityForResult() when you'll be expecting a result from the activity you're starting eg when you're starting a camera activity and you want to use the photo taken in your parent activity - as written in the docs https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: @Optimus Do you know how to open the settings of the app or at the clear defaults of the app ?

Comment: `startActivityForResult()` is deprecated.

Answer (score 17):

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

Answer (score 3):

just sharing for Kotlin sample codes:-

```
val dialogIntent = Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS)
dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
startActivity(dialogIntent)
```