# Android Action Bar Search

Tags: java, android

I am a newcomer to android and am using Eclipse to learn to write action bars.
Code for res/menu/main:

```
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Code for MainActivity.java:

```
   public boolean OnOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_search:
        openSearch();
        return true;
    case R.id.action_settings:
        openSettings();
        return true;
        default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

However, there is a bug regarding R.id.action_search. It is said that it cannot be resolved or is not a field. How can I solve it?

One more question, am I going to define openSearch() and openSettings by myself or they are defined?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your project have to be built automatically to have the R.id working properly.

For your second question, if you want to open the system settings you should look here: [How to open Settings of Android Phone on a button click in our Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966308/how-to-open-settings-of-android-phone-on-a-button-click-in-our-android-app)

For the search, I don't know if you're looking for a search bar or opening Google search, but for a search bar you should look at the section Add an action view on this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView

Comment: Thank you very much. How could I built the project automatically?

Comment: In the menu Project you have an option Build Automatically